# Crystal language: is the first argument to delay in seconds or milliseconds?

Tags: crystal-lang

I'm looking to use the [delay](https://crystal-lang.org/api/0.24.2/toplevel.html#delay%28delay%2C%26block%3A-%3E_%29-class-method) method, but am unsure as to what unit of time the first argument is.

As a follow-up, is the argument an integer, float, or something else?

Comment: If you are wondering if it is seconds or milliseconds, surely a quick test will give you the answer faster than writing a Stack Overflow question and waiting for an answer.

Comment: The thought had occurred to me, but I'd like for others to be able to look up these answers in the future.

Comment: Looking at the example in the (incomplete) documentation, seconds seem most plausible. A delay of 1 millisecond isn't too useful

Answer (score 3):

The implementation calls `to_f` on the argument internally and interprets it as seconds, so you can pass anything that responds in a compatible way. This includes [Time::Span](https://crystal-lang.org/api/0.24.2/Time/Span.html) instances, so things like `delay(5.minutes) { puts "done" }` work.

Answer (score 1):

The delay time is in seconds, and is a float (or other number type with decimal precision)